# Avoid this for loop with Lambdaj

Tags: java, lambdaj

How can avoid this loop with lambdaj, I want to add all elements from List personas into another list

```
String tipo = "type_1";
for (Person person : personas) {
    lista.add(new SimpleResultForm(tipo, person));
}
```

I'm using Java 7 so, Java 8 lambda expresions won't work, I need a solution arround [Lambdaj library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.lambdaj/lambdaj/2.2)

Comment: http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/collections/java-8-tutorial-streams-by-examples/

Answer (score 0):

With java 8:

```
String tipo = "type_1";
lista = personas.stream()
             .map(person -> new SimpleResultForm(tipo, person))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And in case lista already contains data:

```
String tipo = "type_1";
lista.addAll(personas.stream()
             .map(person -> new SimpleResultForm(tipo, person))
             .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score -1):

In Java 8, assume you had already created the list "lista", then this one-liner should do the work.

```
String tipo = "type_1";
personas.stream().forEach(e -> lista.add(new SimpleResultForm(tipo, e)));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.